# how to read certain files in a directory in excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I want to read certain excel files from a directory and then open them in [excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007) with  VBA.

Here is an example:
directory: `c:\temp`
file pattern: is `xxxxx0123.xls` (xxxxx represents the file names).

I try to use `Application.FileSearch`, but it won't work in Excel 2007. Does any one have good suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need to do with the files? There might be a better solution than looping through and opening each of them up.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `DIR` to find files matching your pattern, ie this code opens these files, grabs their path, and closes the files again

The code can be made recursive if you need to look in sub-folders

```
Sub GetFiles()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    strFolder = "C:\temp"
    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "\*123.xls")
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        Debug.Print wb.FullName
        wb.Close False
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. I could never understand why they removed application.filesearch :) BTW since the user is using Excel 2007, you might want to change "\*123.xls" to "\*123.xls*"

Comment: @SiddharthRout normally I would do that wildcard suggestion (and it was worth raising as you did) but the question did specify ".xls"