# How to write an autofit columns script to handle multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, perl

I have hundreds of excel files every month and I need a faster way to autofit the columns to the correct size. As of now I open each file and click the top left corner of each file highlight all and click on one column heading to open all columns to the largest inputted line. Is there any what to write something that could open the excel files and open all columns to correct size. I am new to perl but have been learning what I can.. most of everything I see is about creating a new file. Not sure where to start.. any Ideas..

Comment: For a VBA solution, you would loop through each file, open it, modifying the colmns then save it. Most of that is covered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202456/how-to-read-certain-files-in-a-directory-in-excel-vba/9202918#9202918