# VBA to copy a cell from multiple workbooks into specific cells in the another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, extract

i have around 500 workbooks each one contains 5 sheets i want to extract data from specific cells  in sheet 1 and 2 and 3 (lest say sheet 1 needs cells B2,B6,B8. and sheet 2 cells B2,C2,D2 and sheet 3 B6,D6) then past them into one sheet in specific order (lest say from sheet one goes to A,B,C columns respectively and from sheet 2 follows in columns D,E,F, then from sheet 3 also follows columns G,H,I.
In short i want to make a table from the extracted cells

thanks in advance

Comment: You can record macro and then do the above for one workbook and then loop over that code for each of your 500 workbooks.. If you increment destination row number each time, you'll soon have your table.

Comment: Ok, you have explained what you want to do, good. So, what is your question? Do you have a specific problem with your task? (Or, are you expecting somebody to do all your work?)

Comment: @Cyrus this is what i ended up after recording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution to your question. The code contains the recorded code, which has not yet been completely edited. I'm leaving that to you to complete. There are instructions in the comments in the code below. I'm autistic; so I can sometimes appear to school others, when I'm only trying to help.

The recorded code seems to have omitted a few of the source ranges like "B2" which will need to be manually corrected

The part of the code, which identifies the files in the folder was taken from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202456/how-to-read-certain-files-in-a-directory-in-excel-vba)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test15()

Dim iRow&
Dim FileName$, sPath$
Dim wb As Workbook, wbSurvey As Workbook
Dim wsSurvey As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet

sPath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\HP Laptop\Documents\Documents\Jobs\DIT\IDMB\Stack Overflow\okinawa\"

Set wbSurvey = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSurvey = wbSurvey.Sheets("Survey")

'FileName = Dir(strFolder & "\*123.xls")
FileName = Dir(sPath)
iRow = 2
Do While Len(FileName) > 0
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & FileName)
    
    'change the phrase FIRST TAB here to the name of the first sheet, which is used in your process.
    Set WS = wb.Sheets("FIRST TAB")
    
    'this is how the edited code below needs to look. cutcopymode and scroll down lines of code can be deleted
    WS.Range("B2").Copy
    wsSurvey.Range("B" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    'this is an example of which lines of code need to be edited to look like the above two lines of code.
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("C" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("D" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("E" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("F" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("G" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    Set WS = wb.Sheets("RF")
    
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("H" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("I" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("I2").Select
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("J" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("K" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("B9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("L" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("M" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("N" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("O" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("P" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("B21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("Q" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B22").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("R" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B23").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("S" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("T" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B25").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("U" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B26").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("V" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    Range("C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("W" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("X" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("Y" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("Z" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AA" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AB" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AC" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AD" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AE" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("C14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AF" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("C21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AG" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C22").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AH" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C23").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AI" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AJ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C25").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AK" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C26").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AL" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
    Range("D4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AM" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AN" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AO" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AP" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AQ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AR" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AS" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AT" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AU" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("D14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AV" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AW" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D22").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AX" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("D23").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AY" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("AZ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D25").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BA" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("D26").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BB" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    Set WS = wb.Sheets("TI&PW")
    
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("BD" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BE" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("BF" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BG" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BH" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("C18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BJ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BK" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BL" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F19").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BM" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C20").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BN" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F20").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Range("BP" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BQ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("C27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BR" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BS" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C28").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BT" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F28").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BU" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C29").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BV" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F29").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BW" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BX" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BY" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C31").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("BZ" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F31").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("CA" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("C32").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("CB" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS. _
        Activate
    Range("F32").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    wsSurvey
    Range("CC" & iRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    wb.Close (False)
    FileName = Dir
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, friend, then please accept it as the correct answer ? You can do so by clicking the large "V" tick at the top of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

this is what i ended up with after recording

Sub Extract_Data()
'
' Extract_Data Macro
'

```
enter 
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("G2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Sheets("RF").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-54
Range("B4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("H2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("I2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("J2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("K2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("B9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("L2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("M2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("N2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("O2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("P2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("B21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("Q2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("R2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("S2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("T2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("U2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("V2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
Range("C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("W2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("X2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AC2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AD2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AE2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("C14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AF2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("C21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AG2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AH2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AI2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AJ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AK2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AL2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
Range("D4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AM2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AN2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AO2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AP2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AQ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AR2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AS2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AT2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AU2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
Range("D14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AV2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D15").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AW2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AX2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("D23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AY2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("AZ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("D26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BC2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Sheets("TI&PW").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
Range("D2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BD2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("B3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BE2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BF2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BG2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BH2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BI2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("C18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BJ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BK2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BL2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BM2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BN2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BO2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BP2").Select
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BQ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Range("C27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BR2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BS2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BT2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BU2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C29").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BV2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F29").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BW2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C30").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BX2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F30").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BY2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C31").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("BZ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F31").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("CA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("C32").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("CB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Scopes_13753_PO11 WL MW TSSR_GeneratedDraft_20220807171314.xlsx"). _
    Activate
Range("F32").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Survey Data Base.xlsx").Activate
Range("CC2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub
code here

Comment: If people offer answers to your question, the order of your codes will change, making it more confusing to future readers. At the bottom of your question is an edit link which enables you to add your code to your question. Apologies for not making that clear before. Questions have no limit to their size. So if you add the code to your question it will appear as a single block making it much easier for the volunteers trying to help you to understand.

Comment: By answering your own question, your question is now marked as answered and less volunteers may view it thinking it's now solved

Answer (score -1):

@Cyrus this is the list of actions needed

nb :
all needed sheets in all workbooks have the same names and order

```
enterSheets("Basic Information").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B2").Select
Range("B5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C2").Select
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D2").Select
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E2").Select
Range("F5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F2").Select
Range("D5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("G2").Select
Sheets("RF").Select
Range("B4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("H2").Select
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("I2").Select
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("J2").Select
Range("B8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("K2").Select
Range("B9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("L2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("M2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("N2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("O2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("P2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("Q2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("R2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("S2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("T2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("U2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("V2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("W2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("C6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("X2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AC2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AD2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AE2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AF2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AG2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AH2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AI2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AJ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AK2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AL2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AM2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AN2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AO2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AP2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D9").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AQ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AR2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AS2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AT2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AU2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AV2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D15").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AW2").Select
Range("D21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AX2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AY2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("AZ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BC2").Select
Sheets("TI&PW").Select
Range("D2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BD2").Select
Range("F2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BE2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BF2").Select
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BG2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BH2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BI2").Select
Range("F12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BJ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BK2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BL2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BM2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BN2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BO2").Select
Range("F20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy`enter code here`
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("BP2").Select
Range("C21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F21").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BQ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BR2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BS2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BT2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BU2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C29").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BV2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F29").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BW2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C30").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BX2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F30").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BY2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C31").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("BZ2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F31").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("CA2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C32").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("CB2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F32").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("CC2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste code here
```

Comment: Thanks for recording these codes. If you choose not to edit your question above, then can you let me know which of your answers contains the first part of the code?

Comment: @Cyrus the first answer is the one contains the whole code the whole recording , the second answers contains the actions only copy cell past cell (the same same action in the first answer)

Comment: I think the first answer you added to this page now appears second on this page. Is that correct?

Comment: @Cyrus yes correct

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. What is difference between the two answers? You say that your first answer contains the whole recording but it has no workbook references; whilst your second answer contains the needed workbook references.

Comment: @Cyrus yes that's correct

Comment: Dear okinawa. Is it safe for me to solve your question using just your first answer then?

Comment: Dear okinawa. Apologies. I confused your answers. Hopefully you'll incorporate your answers in your question next time. It'll make it so much easier. Is it safe for me to solve your question using just your second answer then?

Comment: @Cyrus ok go ahead

Comment: Dear okinawa. You started recording the macro after opening the two documents so it didn't record the name of the first sheet you were copying and pasting. What is the name of that first tab which has the same name in both documents?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).